# How to Mock this.HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync() in c# core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, mocking, moq

I'm trying to Mock a call of this.HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync(), which returns an WebSocket object.
My class are as follows:

```
public abstract class HttpContext
{
    protected HttpContext();
    public abstract WebSocketManager WebSockets { get; }
}

public abstract class WebSocketManager
{
    protected WebSocketManager();
    public abstract Task<WebSocket> AcceptWebSocketAsync(string subProtocol);
}

using (var webSocket = Task.Run(async () => await 
this.HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync()))
{​​​​
    socketConn.CreateConnectionHandler(obj1, obj2, webSocket.Object);
}​​​​
```

I tried mocking CreateConnectionHandler method over the interface as well but internally it is using a concrete object so it didn't help.
How can I mock HttpContext to get the WebSocket method mocked object.?
Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you access `HttpContext`?  Via `IHttpContextAccessor`?

Comment: Where has been the `socketConn` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to mock the `HttpContext` with the mocked `WebSocketManager` you only need to `Mock<>` the desired class, and use the `Setup()` delegation to return the instantiated mocked object with `Return(**.Object)`:

The mocked WebSocket:

```
Mock<System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket> mockedWebSocket = new Mock<System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket>();
mockedWebSocket
    .Setup(x => x.SendAsync(It.IsAny<ArraySegment<byte>>(),
                It.IsAny<System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType>(),
                It.IsAny<bool>(),
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(true)); //Assuming boolean result - you will need to changed the return value according to the test case.
```

The mocked WebSocketManager:

```
Mock<WebSocketManager> mockedWebSocketManager = new Mock<WebSocketManager>();
mockedWebSocketManager
    .Setup(x => x.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockedWebSocket.Object));
```

The mocked HttpContext:

```
Mock<HttpContext> mockedHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
    mockedHttpContext.Setup(x => x.WebSockets)
    .Returns(mockedWebSocketManager.Object);
```

Please add `using Moq;`